# How to animate image position in CSS?

Tags: html, css

The code is down,I wanted to add images instead,so that 5 images will be moved.I try here to put my code for some reasons it didn't let me post it. I write only the first ,but in similar way I did and the other 4. **div1 {  background-image: url("newphoto1.jpg"); }** .That image reffer to div1.It didn't work.The original code is this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style> 
div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: red;
  font-weight: bold;
  position: relative;
  animation: mymove 5s infinite;
}

#div1 {animation-timing-function: linear;}
#div2 {animation-timing-function: ease;}
#div3 {animation-timing-function: ease-in;}
#div4 {animation-timing-function: ease-out;}
#div5 {animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;}

@keyframes mymove {
  from {left: 0px;}
  to {left: 300px;}
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<p><strong>Note:</strong> The animation-timing-funtion property is not supported in Internet Explorer 9 and earlier versions.</p>

<div id="div1">linear</div>
<div id="div2">ease</div>
<div id="div3">ease-in</div>
<div id="div4">ease-out</div>
<div id="div5">ease-in-out</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You mean the image wasn't showing up?

Comment: @MichaelTr7 yes ,I want instead of the red box to make an image move like this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Adding `background-size:` Tag to Avoid Clipping:

Try maybe possible adding this code snippet to each element in the CSS file. Possible the image is being clipped by setting `background-size:` to `background-size: 100% 100%;` this will fill the entire `<div>`/box. If you prefer to not distort the image use `background-size: cover;` and then set the position using `background-position:`.

[image: Result]

### CSS Snippet (CSS):

```
background-image: url('./newphoto1.jpg'); 
background-size: 100% 100%;
```

### Playground Script (HTML/CSS):

Below I used some random test images in this runnable playground script:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style> 
div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: red;
  font-weight: bold;
  position: relative;
  animation: mymove 5s infinite;
}

#div1 {animation-timing-function: linear;
    background-image: url('https://picsum.photos/200'); 
    background-size: 100% 100%;
}
#div2 {animation-timing-function: ease;
    background-image: url('https://picsum.photos/200'); 
    background-size: 100% 100%;
}
#div3 {animation-timing-function: ease-in;
    background-image: url('https://picsum.photos/200'); 
    background-size: 100% 100%;
}
#div4 {animation-timing-function: ease-out;
    background-image: url('https://picsum.photos/200'); 
    background-size: 100% 100%;
}
#div5 {animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
    background-image: url('https://picsum.photos/200'); 
    background-size: 100% 100%;
}

@keyframes mymove {
  from {left: 0px;}
  to {left: 300px;}
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<p><strong>Note:</strong> The animation-timing-funtion property is not supported in Internet Explorer 9 and earlier versions.</p>

<div id="div1">linear</div>
<div id="div2">ease</div>
<div id="div3">ease-in</div>
<div id="div4">ease-out</div>
<div id="div5">ease-in-out</div>

</body>
</html>
```

**Note it takes about a second for the images to load in this playground script and take effect.*